# watir webdriver try catch proxy

Tags: testing, watir, watir-webdriver

Here are working codes for connecting proxy with watir webdriver:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--proxy-server=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80]
```

Now if the proxy don't work, how can I catch that and try with other one?
like try and catch or with cases?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can only determine if the proxy works by going to a page. If Chrome cannot connect to the proxy, it displays a message of "Unable to connect to the proxy server." Therefore, you can try:

1) Going to a page using a proxy
 2) Check for the message
 3) If the message appears, try another proxy
 4) If the message does not appear, the proxy works

For example, the following will attempt the first proxy, which will fail. It will then go to try the next proxy, etc.

```
proxy_servers = ['111.111.11.111:80', '222.222.22.222:80']

browser = nil

proxy_servers.each do |proxy|
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => ["--proxy-server=#{proxy}"]

    # Try going to a page
    browser.goto 'http://www.google.ca'

    #If Chrome says "Unable to connect to the proxy server", try another one
    if browser.text.include?('Unable to connect to the proxy server')
        browser.close
    else
        break
    end
end

# Throw an exception if a valid proxy server cannot be found
raise 'No valid proxy servers found' unless browser.exists?
```